# setup nginx as load balancer

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a lamp stack running on localhost, I have installed wordpress.
I have setup apache on localhost listening on two ports 8080 and 8090.
Now, I need to setup nginx on top of as loadbalancer, I getting 302 errors.

Please help

Nginx config:

```
 upstream backend  {
   server 127.0.0.1:8080;
   server 127.0.0.1:8090;
 }
server {

   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;

  location /wp-admin/ {
     proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }
}
```

## Error from access.log:

`x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2017:05:33:42 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/x.x.x.x Safari/537.36" "-"`

Comment: Your ports looks incorrect, you said 8080 and 9090 but your upstream config is 8005 and 8006

Comment: @FarhadFarahi That was typo

Comment: What do you see when connect to apache backend directly?